# Subtract two queries using WITH

Tags: sql, sql-server

So i wanted to find the products that exist in all customer invoices by using NOT EXIST. I have create two temporary tables by using WITH and subsequently i am trying to subtract them to find the result, however i get this error

> Msg 422, Level 16, State 4, Line 28
>   Common table expression defined but not used.

Here's what i have done until now.

```
DECLARE @startdate datetime = '2010-01-01 08:56:01.49';
DECLARE @enddate datetime = '2010-01-02 10:43:17.283';

With AllProducts AS 

(
SELECT P.PRODUCT_ID,
   P.PRODUCT_NAME,
   CONCAT(DATENAME(MONTH, @startdate), '''', RIGHT(DATENAME(YEAR, 
@startdate), 2)) AS StardPeriod,
   CONCAT(DATENAME(MONTH, @enddate), '''', RIGHT(DATENAME(YEAR, @enddate), 
2)) AS EndPeriod
FROM Products$ P
 ),
ProductNotExistInInvoices AS 

(
SELECT P.PRODUCT_ID,
   P.PRODUCT_NAME,
   CONCAT(DATENAME(MONTH, @startdate), '''', RIGHT(DATENAME(YEAR, 
@startdate), 2)) AS StardPeriod,
       CONCAT(DATENAME(MONTH, @enddate), '''', RIGHT(DATENAME(YEAR, 
@enddate), 2)) AS EndPeriod
FROM Products$ P
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                 FROM Invoices$ I
   JOIN InvDetails$ ID ON I.INVOICE_ID = ID.INVOICE_ID
              WHERE I.INVOICE_DATE BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate
                AND ID.PRODUCT_ID = P.PRODUCT_ID)
 ) 

 SELECT (AllProducts)-(ProductNotExistInInvoices) AS Result
```

Comment: Why arnt you rewitting this to a simple tablea left join tableb where tableb.column IS NULL kind of query

Answer (score 0):

You want `NOT EXISTS` :

```
SELECT A.*
FROM AllProducts A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ProductNotExistInInvoices N WHERE A.PRODUCT_ID = N.PRODUCT_ID)
```

Comment: Its correct but i also get null values which i dont want them.How i am going to deal with this?

Comment: @Loopinfility. . . `Null` value means what ? How did you get the `Null` ?